# ValidationProvider rule for url checks

Tags: vue.js, vee-validate

In  @vue/cli 4.0.5 app I need to add additive URL checks to `ValidationProvider` rules. My code:

```html
<ValidationProvider
    name="website"
    rules="{ required : true, url: {require_protocol: true} }"
    v-slot="{ errors }"
>
```

But got this console error:

> No such validator '{ required ' exists.

With `rules`:

```html
    rules="required : true, url: {require_protocol: true}"
```

Error is:

> No such validator 'required ' exists.

Which format is valid?

```json
    "vee-validate": "^3.1.0",
    "vue": "^2.6.10",
```

**MODIFIED BLOCK :**

With rules :

```
:rules="{ required : true, url: {require_protocol: true} }"
```

I got next error :

```
vee-validate.esm.js?7bb1:708 Uncaught (in promise) Error: No such validator 'url' exists.
```

I expected all methods must be accessible, as I have in import part:

```
...
import {ValidationObserver, ValidationProvider, extend} from 'vee-validate'
import * as rules from 'vee-validate/dist/rules';

Object.keys(rules).forEach(rule => {
    extend(rule, rules[rule]);
});
import {localize} from 'vee-validate';
```

What is wrong ?

**MODIFIED BLOCK #2 :**

In vue file

```
   <ValidationProvider
        name="website"
        :rules="{ required : true }"
        v-slot="{ errors }"
    >


...

import { ValidationObserver, ValidationProvider } from 'vee-validate'
import { required, email } from 'vee-validate/dist/rules' // MY PHP STORM shows this line in gray color as nonused elements
```

I still got error :

```
vee-validate.esm.js?7bb1:708 Uncaught (in promise) Error: No such validator 'required' exists.
```

I found file /node_modules/vee-validate/dist/rules.js with lines :

```
var required = {
    validate: validate$o,
    params: params$h,
    computesRequired: computesRequired
};

var testEmpty = function (value) {
    return isEmptyArray(value) || includes([false, null, undefined], value) || !String(value).trim().length;
};
var validate$p = function (value, _a) {
    var target = _a.target, values = _a.values;
    var required;
    if (values && values.length) {
        if (!Array.isArray(values) && typeof values === 'string') {
            values = [values];
        }
        // eslint-disable-next-line
        required = values.some(function (val) { return val == String(target).trim(); });
    }
    else {
        required = !testEmpty(target);
    }
    if (!required) {
        return {
            valid: true,
            required: required
        };
    }
    return {
        valid: !testEmpty(value),
        required: required
    };
};
...
```

I do not see error syntax comparing with samples/provided link 
I declared ValidationObserver, ValidationProvider before required declaration.
Where is the error ?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried adding `Vue.component('ValidationProvider', ValidationProvider)` and 
`Vue.component('ValidationObserver', ValidationObserver)` where you import the rules, and then remove the import of those in the actual file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In [this example](http://vee-validate.logaretm.com/v2/guide/components/validation-provider.html#examples) they use a pipe character (`|`) to separate the string rules:

```html
<ValidationProvider rules="required|confirmed:confirm" v-slot="{ errors }">
...
```

However, if you want to pass an object as you are now (which may be best because it's more complex than that example) then you need to bind the `rules` prop:

```html
<ValidationProvider
  v-bind:rules="{ required : true, ... }"
  ...
>

<!-- Or shorthand binding syntax with : -->
:rules="{ required : true, ... }"
```

To explain the error you're currently seeing:

> No such validator '{ required ' exists.

That's because, without binding the `rules` prop, you're passing a raw string rather than an object. So it's interpreting `{ required` as the name of a validator, when that clearly is not a valid validator name.

**ADDITION**

Per this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/logaretm/vee-validate/issues/2297):

> Now VeeValidate requires you to import the rules yourself. So you can either >import them rule by rule:
>
> `import { required, email } from 'vee-validate/dist/rules';`
>
> or you can import all rules once using:
>
> ```javascript
> import {
>  ValidationProvider,
>  ValidationObserver
> } from 'vee-validate/dist/vee-validate.full';
> ```

Comment: Thanks! Please look at MODIFIED BLOCK

Comment: It's probably not a great idea to import every rule if you're not going to use all of them. Instead, why not just `import { required, confirmed, url, ...etc } from 'vee-validate'` for the rules you need?

Comment: I tried to leave 1 line :     import {ValidationObserver, ValidationProvider, required, confirmed, url} from 'vee-validate'
but got error : Error: No such validator 'required' exists.  Error in syntax ?

Comment: Sorry about that. I've updated my answer. You don't import from `vee-validate` (which I had in my last comment).

Comment: This does not work still! Please look at MODIFIED BLOCK #2